# How do you best store a ID that has to persistent from login to logout

Tags: asp.net-mvc, persistence, session-variables

What's the best way to persist let's say an ID from the time a user logs in (Claims) until the time the user logs out either manually or through a session timeout? I tried using a static class but it gets disposed and thus my properties are null.

Is HttpContext.Current.Session a viable solution here? So that I can basically do this when the user logs in:

```
HttpContext.Current.Session["MyCustomID"] = somevalue;
```

and when the user logs out:

```
HttpContext.Current.Session["MyCustomID"] = null;
```

Comment: One thing I may warn you w/ is that it may be possible to perform session hijacking if your auth is based on a plaintext number stored as a session variable.  I can't confirm this is a viable attack path, but it just sounds like a  possibility to me.  I use ASP.Identity for getting access to userID / session variables etc, I'm assuming you already checked that out and don't want to implement that here...?

Comment: I already used ASP Identity for my authentication and I store the ID of the logged on user there. But I also need to store a dynamic ID which can change during the user's session. Can you store dynamic information with ASP Identity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the best solution to be storing it in DB, this way you can always match it to the original session UID. It also helps me to log things related to each session. The downside is the speed and it gets trickier when you have many visitors so you want to keep the amount of the data reads/writes to a minimum.

You can also mimic other server's solutions i.e. write it in a temp file and again mange and limit the I/O to minimum. I like the DB solution better though.

The bottom line is that the session can be lost due to many reasons (i.e.: server restart, app recompile, session time out, app pool refresh, etc..) so holding it in memory will always be susceptible to a loss regardless of which object is being used i.e: HttpContext.Current.Session (session state), singleton class with one large dictionary of current sessions, static class etc.

Comment: sorry I totally forgot to get back to your answer. I ended up using a database table for storing session variables in a Key-Value pair fashion. As an identifier I didn't use the session's UID but the ID of the logged in user, which I store in a Claim with Type NameIdentifier. Not perfect, but it serves my purpose.